# Create Map using only the town or the city name ( python - Dash )

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a data where I only have the town or the city in each observation.
Is it possible to only use the town name or the city name to show the number of observation and their location on a map and color them with field called target ?

I am using dash with python.

example of input data :

| Index | city | town | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Noord-Holland | Amsterdam | 0 |
| 1 | Noord-Holland | Amsterdam | 1 |
| 2 | Arizona | Phoenix | 2 |
| 3 | Washington | Redmond | 1 |
| 4 | Washington | Redmond | 2 |
| 5 | Washington | Seattle | 0 |

desired output :

map that that shows there is 3 observation in Washington, 2 observations from Noord-Holland and 1 from Arizona colored with the field target ( if possible we could use bubble to highlight the number of observations). PS: we can use the town instead of the city.

**I am using Dash and  python**,
Thank you

Comment: hey, you need to get the gps coordinates for each city (try geopy library) and then you can use the coordinates to plot the data on a bubble map or a mapbox map available on plotly : https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/

Comment: Thank you I will try that.